# Noob to scala path dependent types

Tags: scala, traits, path-dependent-type

I am unclear how to achieve path dependent types in the following snippet. The intention is to be able to use the "meld" method to merge two Heaps. That AFAIK requires path dependent types.

Here is the trait

```
trait Heap {
  type H // type of a heap
  type A // type of an element
  def ord: Ordering[Heap#A] // ordering on elements
  def meld(h1: Heap#H, h2: Heap#H): Heap#H // the heap resulting from merging h1 and h2
 ..
}
```

Here is part of the implementation

```
class HeapImpl extends Heap {

  override type H = HeapImpl // this.type
  override type A = Integer
  ..

  // the heap resulting from inserting x into h
  override def meld(h1: Heap#H, h2: Heap#H): Heap#H = {
    while (!isEmpty(h2)) {
      insert(deleteMin(h2),h1)
    }
    this
  }
```

The return value "this" on the meld method suffers the compilation error:

```
Expression HeapImpl does not conform to expected type Heap#H
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
trait Heap {
  type H <: Heap // type of a heap (added requirement that it must be a heap)
  type A // type of an element
  def ord: Ordering[A] // ordering on elements
  def meld(h1: H, h2: H): H // the heap resulting from merging h1 and h2
 ..
}
```

Now, when you define

```
override def meld(h1: H, h2: H): H
```

in `HeapImpl`, `H` is just `HeapImpl` and the return type will conform.

This way, `A` and `H` in the methods are the same as defined in your `type ...`. Path-dependent types mean that you can write types like `heap.A` (where `heap` is a `Heap`).

I'll also note that your implementation of `meld` looks strange. It looks like you are inserting elements of `h2` into `h1` (if not, what does the second argument to `insert` mean?), but then instead of returning `h1` you return `this`.

Answer (score 2):

The projection Heap#H is not the same as this.H.

```
scala> trait Heap { type H ; type A ; def m(h1: H, h2: H): H }
defined trait Heap

scala> class Impl extends Heap { type H = Impl; def m(h1: H, h2: H) = this }
defined class Impl
```